# Using the geocomplete to limit results to country and state

Tags: jquery, geocomplete

I'm using [Geocomplete - jQuery Geocoding and Places Autocomplete Plugin](http://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/) and I'm trying to limit the results returned in the following way. I need:

- Country: Australia
- State: Queensland

with the suggestions limited to:

- Post Code
- Suburb

I can limit to AUS with no problem but the rest is proving difficult. Reading through the [types](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#Types) I believe I need to use `administrative_area_level_1` to get the State and then `postal_code` and `neighborhood` to limit the suggestions? I'm just totally stuck on how to do it.

```
$("input").geocomplete({
  country: 'AUS',
  types: ["postal_code", "neighborhood"], // Doesn't work
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `types` with `type`, because `types` is deprecated.

```
$("input").geocomplete({
    country: 'AUS',
    type: ["postal_code", "neighborhood"]
});
```

But since Google Maps API itself doesn't always return consistent results, it might be necessary to further filter response results. If you log `geocode:result` event's result to a console, you can see the whole material and decide what to with parts.

```
$("input").geocomplete({
    country: 'AUS',
    type: ["postal_code", "neighborhood"]
}).bind("geocode:result", function(event, result){
    console.log(result);
});
```

I needed to do similar thing like you and I found `adr_address` property to be quite useful. It is a HTML formatted string consisting of several `span` elements with self-descriptive classes, like:

```
<span class="street-address">Vippebakke</span>, <span class="postal-code">3740</span> <span class="locality">Svaneke</span>, <span class="country-name">Denmark</span>
```

So it can be appended somewhere invisible and then you can use particular elements inside it.